# Xamarin issue when the app go OnSleep using the back button

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

im having an issue with mi xamarin app, if my app go onSleep using the home button of the phone its resume with no problem, but if i use the back button the app stay freeze in a white screen and never hits the OnResume(), i want it to have the same behavior or at least that using the back button close the app entirely

Code

```
protected override void OnStart ()
    {
        // Handle when your app starts
    }
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        App.IsInBackgrounded = false;
    }
    protected override void OnSleep ()
    {
        // Handle when your app sleeps
        base.OnSleep();
        App.IsInBackgrounded = true;
    }
```

The Output when i use the home button

```
12-23 11:23:35.517 D/ViewRootImpl@b3d0e31[MainActivity](15966): Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2340) new=(0,0,1080,2340) req=(1080,2340)4 dur=21 res=0x1 s={false 0} ch=false
12-23 11:23:35.518 D/ViewRootImpl@b3d0e31[MainActivity](15966): stopped(false) old=true
12-23 11:23:35.620 D/ViewRootImpl@b3d0e31[MainActivity](15966): stopped(false) old=false
12-23 11:23:35.705 D/ViewRootImpl@b3d0e31[MainActivity](15966): Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2340) new=(0,0,1080,2340) req=(1080,2340)0 dur=28 res=0x7 s={true 530976370688} ch=true
12-23 11:23:35.705 D/OpenGLRenderer(15966): createReliableSurface : 0x7bf7e1bf80, 0x7ba0a87000
12-23 11:23:35.739 D/mali_winsys(15966): EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
12-23 11:23:35.950 I/om.kuwaidev.tp(15966): Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 2262(149KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 3171KB/6343KB, paused 77us total 27.240ms
12-23 11:23:35.954 D/Mono    (15966): GC_TAR_BRIDGE bridges 537 objects 25741 opaque 12967 colors 537 colors-bridged 537 colors-visible 537 xref 7 cache-hit 0 cache-semihit 0 cache-miss 0 setup 0.10ms tarjan 19.63ms scc-setup 0.18ms gather-xref 0.01ms xref-setup 0.01ms cleanup 2.11ms
12-23 11:23:35.954 D/Mono    (15966): GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for 34.77ms
12-23 11:23:35.954 D/Mono    (15966): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) time 35.83ms, stw 37.16ms promoted 675K major size: 8784K in use: 7971K los size: 7168K in use: 5791K
12-23 11:23:35.983 D/ViewRootImpl@b3d0e31[MainActivity](15966): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1
12-23 11:23:35.984 D/InputMethodManager(15966): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@fbe4d10[MainActivity]
12-23 11:23:35.984 D/InputMethodManager(15966): getNavigationBarColor() -11427245
12-23 11:23:36.002 D/InputMethodManager(15966): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@fbe4d10[MainActivity]
12-23 11:23:36.002 D/InputMethodManager(15966): getNavigationBarColor() -11427245
12-23 11:23:36.003 V/InputMethodManager(15966): Starting input: tba=com.kuwaidev.tpv ic=null mNaviBarColor -11427245 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
12-23 11:23:36.003 D/InputMethodManager(15966): startInputInner - Id : 0
12-23 11:23:36.003 I/InputMethodManager(15966): startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
```

the output when i use the back button [output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W5WCeEzASjtPnhhsLmwNaQunloy0X5L_/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Back button on Android exits the App.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Back and Home buttons act differently through the application lifecycle events.
Pressing home will background the application; therefore it will pass through OnResume when launching the application again. Contrarywise, pressing Back kills the application. It will therefore pass through the OnStart when launching again.

Here is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/activity-lifecycle/#back-vs-home) supporting.